# mysql_fetch_array returns duplicate data

Tags: php, mysql

every time i run mysql_fetch_array an array is returned with duplicate values **e.g.**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [row_id] => 1
    [1] => some text
    [first_field] => some text
    [2] => some text
    [second_field] => some text 
}
```

but I only want single results in the array, I have tried using

```
mysql_fetch_array($data, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

But this makes no difference.

Comment: Show your query and your table structure.

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql` extension anymore! It's better to use PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: @ComFreek this is a private app that only I will use, for now its not a big problem using mysql but when I have time i'll change to MySqlLi

Comment: @mk_89: you didn't post your query and table structure. Hard to give accurate answers without that.

Comment: with actual PDO, use `$row = $streq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the intended functionality of [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array). If you want to not have the "duplicates" and just have the associative-array, use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) instead.

Example:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) { ... }
```

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array($data, MYSQL_ASSOC);` will do exactly the same as mysql_fetch_assoc.

Comment: @Jocelyn I am aware of that - however - there is no way using `MYSQL_ASSOC` would return an array with the output the OP displayed, as per the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).

Comment: @mk_89 I just tested with `mysql_fetch_array($data, MYSQL_ASSOC)` and cannot replicate (i.e. - it's working how it should) so I cannot answer as to why it would fail in your case. Try using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 5):

mysql_fetch_array returns resultset returned as as response to query execution as both associative and numeric arrays.
For returning resultset as associative array you need to use mysql_fetch_assoc function.
For returning resultset as numeric array you need to use mysql_fetch_row function.

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql_fetch_assoc() for associtive array, or mysql_fetch_row for a numeric array

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array($data, MYSQL_ASSOC);` will do exactly the same as mysql_fetch_assoc.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_array()` returns an array containing both associative keys (the field names specified by queries) and integer position key (i.e. 0 is first field, 1, is second, etc.). This is for convenience in accessing the data by either method.

if you only want the named keys, you should use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`  or better yet, use the mysqli functions as everyone on here will lambast you for using the old mysql_* functions.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array($data, MYSQL_ASSOC);` will do exactly the same as mysql_fetch_assoc.

Comment: @Jocelyn Yes it will. I don't understand the downvote though, as most developer who were familiar with using the old mysql_* functions for any period of time would typically use mysql_fetch_assoc and not have to worry about setting the proper flag on the function call.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)` this has worked for me as suggested above for `mysql_fetch_assoc`, in PHP5.5 it's deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php):

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or
>   FALSE if there are no more rows. **The type of returned array depends
>   on how result_type is defined. By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll
>   get an array with both associative and number indices.** Using
>   MYSQL_ASSOC, you only get associative indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc()
>   works), using MYSQL_NUM, you only get number indices (as
>   mysql_fetch_row() works).

In other words, since MYSQL_BOTH is the default, you get both back. You can specify either  MYSQL_ASSOC or MYSQL_NUM instead to get an associative array or numeric array back. You could also use [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead which will only return an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql_fetch_array() returns indexed as well as associative array. However mysql_fetch_assoc() returns only associative-array.

When mysql_fetch_array used with MYSQLI_NUM parameter returns only an indexed array. 
Example: mysql_fetch_array($resultset,MYSQLI_NUM)