# MySQL PHP printf into $variable adding additional value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm experiencing something strange, and I can't figure out why it's happening. I'm running a query to pull data from a column in a mysql table, and when I do a straight `printf()`, the data comes out as expected. However, when I do `$variable = printf()`, I'm getting an additional value in the string.

The following prints something like:
22611,21435,23327,22876,22986,23692,21581,21832,22337,24313,22174,24368,

```
$query  = "SELECT column FROM table WHERE year in (2012)";
if ($result = mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf ("%s,", $row["column"]);
    }
}
```

But if I try to put the result into a variable like so:

```
$data = printf ("%s,", $row["column"]);
```

I get an output of
22611,21435,23327,22876,22986,23692,21581,21832,22337,24313,22174,24368,6

Why is it adding this extra value? Am I adding the result to the variable incorrectly? FYI, this is just a snippet from the code, I have error handling in place.

Comment: You should have a look at the printf() manual. By the way, why are you using "in" in your request ?

Comment: Because the year is actually a variable, and sometimes its value is "2008,2009,2010" or something to that effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sprintf()` instead (it works exactly like `printf()`). This 'silences' it and gives a return value.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that but when I do `sprintf()`, I'm only getting one value returned. In this instance, it just returns `24368,`

Comment: It's not `sprintf()`, rather, you're not assigning your first `sprintf()` to a variable and appending the rest to it.

Answer (score 2):

`printf()` outputs the data and returns its length. So that's where the extra value is coming from. You want `sprintf()` which just returns the value.

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity, why are you using `sprintf()` at all?

You can assign values to variables directly or with string concatenation.

```
$data = $row["column"];
$data = $row["column"] . ',';
```

Read more about [Strings in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

In this specific case, I would recommend [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode).

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row["column"];
}
echo implode(',', $data);
```

Comment: Totally agree with this OP, `sprint()` is just using more (albeit little) resources.

Comment: This is much better, thanks. I am using this solution. Accepting the first response, though, as I think it answers the question more directly.

Comment: I'm having the same issue mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957541/mysql-fetch-array-returns-duplicate-data). It's adding the array twice even though I'm using `mysql_fetch_assoc()`. Any idea why? That thread that I linked to suggests that mysql_fetch_assoc shouldn't do that.