# mysqli_fetch_assoc returns duplicate data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch

There are very [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957541/mysql-fetch-array-returns-duplicate-data) here, but after a lot of searching and trying different things, I'm still stuck.

When using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` to populate an array, each row is being added twice.

```
$query = "SELECT column FROM table WHERE year = 2012";
if ($result = mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row["column"];
  }
echo implode(',', $data);
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

This is returning the following:
`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

I'm expecting `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

I added a few extra lines to do some debugging...

`print_r($data)` yields

```
Array ( 
[0] => 1 
[1] => 2 
[2] => 3 
[3] => 4 
[4] => 5 
[5] => 6 
[6] => 7 
[7] => 8 
[8] => 9 
[9] => 10 
[10] => 1 
[11] => 2 
[12] => 3 
[13] => 4 
[14] => 5 
[15] => 6 
[16] => 7 
[17] => 8 
[18] => 9 
[19] => 10 )
```

`print_r($result);` yields

```
mysqli_result Object 
( 
[current_field] => 0 
[field_count] => 1 
[lengths] => 
[num_rows] => 10 
[type] => 0 
)
```

If `[num_rows] => 10`, and i'm using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and not `mysqli_fetch_array()`, why is it adding the values to the array twice?

Comment: I'm not an experienced PHP developer - but shouldn't you be using PDO by now?

Comment: @JonClements updated title. He is using mysqli, not mysql_*

Comment: MySQLi is a suitable alternative to PDO.

Comment: Are you certain you are not _reusing_ the variable `$data` from an earlier call, or calling this twice? You are not initializing `$data = array()` beforehand here...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You were right on; thanks. Hello from a fellow Minneapolitan.

Comment: @Mute Cool - I've met just 2 or 3 other Minneapoitans here. Someday I'd like to host a meetup or something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you've already assigned some data to `$data` array. Try to empty it before `while` instruction:

```
$query = "SELECT column FROM table WHERE year = 2012";
if ($result = mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {
  $data = array();
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row["column"];
  }
echo implode(',', $data);
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

and see what it outputs.

I believe `column` is not a real column name otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: You were right; adding `$data = array()` fixed it. Thanks for your help.