# Why are my results echoing multiple times?

Tags: php, mysqli, echo

I'm working on a script that queries a database and displays the average score per department. I have the query working, the only issue being that it's echoing each result twice. I assume it's an issue with the nesting of my while/ foreach  statements but I can't seem to get it worked out.  I've tried moving the } around to several different areas and can't find a solution.  Here is the problem area.

```
$time='Y-m-d';
strtotime(date('Y-m')."-1 month");

$area=array(
  0=> "Assembly &Test ESP",
  1=> "Hermetic ESP",
  2=> "Machine Shop ESP",
  3=> "Maintenance",
  4=> "Mining ESP",
  5=> "Punch Press ESP",
  6=> "Weld Fab ESP",
  7=> "Winding ESP",
  8=> "DMI",
  9=> "Shelby Maintenance",
  10=>"Shelby Machine Shop");


$i=0; 
$post=array();
while($i<11){
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"Select AVG(score) As average FROM RESULTS where esp_unit = '$area[$i]' and time  <'time-30'");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo $area[$i];
    print"</br>";
    foreach($row as $element){
        echo $element."<br>";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please for the love of god don't use while to loop over a collection! You have zero excuse when a foreach loop is both shorter to write and impossible to get wrong.

Comment: Your SQL query is iffy. The `time` column cannot be lower than a string. Also, the `$area[$i]` part needs to be interpolated properly, like `{$area[$i]}`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array returns duplicate data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957541/mysql-fetch-array-returns-duplicate-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_array()` is also setting numeric index keys.

Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` to only set an associative array.

If you would like to debug then add this line after you set your `$row`:

```
// $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($row, true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the exact issue.

Comment: Glad I could help. Doing `echo '<pre>'.print_r($some_array, true).'</pre>';` has saved my butt so many times

Comment: Please consider voting question to close as a duplicate rather answering it. Help to keep the site clean.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Evidently, MonkeyZeus doesn't have enough rep points to do so (vote). You of all people should know that. [Consult Privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: I appreciate the defense Fred -ii- but I think I am actually able to flag it though. Thank you both, I definitely like this site and the power it harnesses.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus No problemo and you're welcome. I was *"just saying"*. I wasn't underestimating your capabilities ;-) Cheers

Comment: Haha I know you weren't. Sometimes a kick in the butt from Your Common Common sense is exactly what people need. Cheers bud

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Some actually forget where they came from and started at the bottom like the rest of us, just as some of the richest people in the world who once were poor and now "look down" at the people who put them there. Cheers MZ ;-)