# When I execute, the table will be 2, but in my code is only 1. Php search and fetch

Tags: php, html, ajax

When I execute, its running but the table is two. Im trying to fetch data from the database using search.

[image: This image shows what is the table show]

Heres the structure:
this is the

//account-settings-server-A.php

```
//search
    $output = '';
    if(isset($_POST["query"]))
    {
     $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["query"]);
     $query = "
      SELECT * FROM users 
      WHERE firstname LIKE '%".$search."%'
      OR lastname LIKE '%".$search."%' 
      OR username LIKE '%".$search."%' 
      OR password LIKE '%".$search."%' 
     ";
    }
    else
    {
     $query = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id";
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
     $output .= '
      <div class="table-responsive">
       <table class="table table bordered">
        <tr>
         <th>Username</th>
         <th>Password</th>
         <th>Lastname</th>
         <th>Firstname</th>
        </tr>
     ';
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
      $output .= '
       <tr>
        <td>'.$row["username"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["password"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["lastname"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["firstname"].'</td>
       </tr>
      ';
     }
     echo $output;
    }
    else
    {
     echo 'Data Not Found';
    }

    ?>
```

and this is the account.settings

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>
        <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search by Customer Details" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <br />
   <div id="result"></div>
        </div>
        <!--div class="content">
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <p>Here you can do fuck</p>
        </div-->
        <!--dashboard-->
</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_data();

 function load_data(query)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"account-settings-server-A.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#result').html(data);
   }
  });
 }
 $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
  var search = $(this).val();
  if(search != '')
  {
   load_data(search);
  }
  else
  {
   load_data();
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

if you have any problem in my question, comment down. Please let me out in this problem thanks

Comment: I don't think it's related the problem, but you need `</table></div>` at the end of `$output`

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would cause the duplication. If you look at the response in the Network tab of Developer tools, do you see 1 table or 2?

Comment: Possibly the answer is to use mysqli_fetch_assoc as described here by newfurniturey https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957541/mysql-fetch-array-returns-duplicate-data
I would recommend PDO for db connection, by the way

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so added a comment, but am convinced that the issue is with this line of code

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

Should be

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
```

I would recommend that you use PDO. If you already know about PDO, this would be how you'd make sure you get 'single' result set.

```
$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

If not, here are some helpful links.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: This sounds right. You can also use `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`